# Why do we consider the third quadrant to decide the sign of sin$(180^° + \theta)$?

Tags: trigonometry

sin$(300^°)$ $=$ sin$(180^°+120^°)$ $=$ **–** sin$(120^°)$

---

In the above example, we have given a negative sign as it is of the form sin$(180^° + \theta)$ and it lies in the *third quadrant where sin is negative*. So we write -sin$(\theta)$. But the angle **180° + 120°** lies in the *fourth quadrant*. So why are we considering the *third quadrant* to decide the sign? Shouldn't we consider the *fourth quadrant*?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Probably some *lapsus calami*.

Comment: Who told you to consider the third quadrant? I never heard of such a thing.

Comment: @Bernard Where?

Comment: When they wrote  ‘third quadrant’. We all commit lapsus from time to time.

Comment: @Bernard they? — What do you mean by "they"? That reference to the third quadrant is not a lapsus.

Comment: Maybe. I suppose you're quoting some text. I meant a lapsus from those who wrote the text. Anyway, it should be better formulated as ‘it lies on the lower semi-unit circle, where the sine is negative’, in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

One of the identities that holds for the sine function is
$$\sin(180° + x) = -\sin(x)$$

which does not require to consider quadrants or anything like that to be used!

Comment: This doesn't help. I know that I can prove it by using sin$(A+B)$. My point was specifically about the quadrants. As sin$(180^° + \theta)$ = $-$sin$(\theta)$, the negative sign comes because $180^° + \theta$ (even if the $\theta$ is not lesser than $90^°$) lies in the third quadrant where sin is negative.

Comment: Well, no. $\sin(200°+180°)=\sin(380°)=\sin(20°)>0$, and yet the formula still holds. Also... note that the sine is also negative in the fourth quadrant?

Comment: I am not sure about your first point. I know that sin is negative in the fourth quadrant. That cannot justify the rule. For example sin$(270^° - 120^°)$, the sign will be **negative** as it is in the third quadrant. My point is why shouldn't I consider the second quadrant to consider the sign of the second quadrant as $270° - 120°$ should ideally lie in the second quadrant?

Comment: Because $\sin(x)$ is a quantity that carries a sign with it, and you are not deciding the sign of $\sin(300°)$ when you put the minus in front of $\sin(120°)$. You are simply applying an algebraic identity. In general, as I showed you, you can get stuff like $-\sin(200°)$ that simplifies to a *positive* quantity.

Comment: I don't think I am applying algebraic identity. To decide the sign, $180^∘+θ$ is taken to be in the third quadrant (as if $θ$ is lesser than $90^∘$), even though $180^∘+120^∘$ does not lie in the third quadrant, but lies in the fourth quadrant. This is consistent with all trigonometric functions. Similarly, $270^∘−θ$ is taken in the third quadrant (to decide the sign), no matter what $θ$ is. My question was "Why this works?"

Comment: It doesn't work. Take $\theta=200°$ and you'll see that it doesn't work.

Comment: Nope, it works perfectly fine. In sin$(180^°+200^°)$, $\theta$ = $200^°$. It's of the form sin$(180^° + \theta)$, so as I told you earlier we will take it in the third quadrant to decide the sign; sin is negative in the third quadrant. So sin$(180^°+200^°)$ $=$ –sin$(200^°)$. You can simplify it further.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Basically you take $\theta=1°$ or something like that, check the sign of $\sin(\Omega + \theta)$ and then you put it in front of $\sin(\theta)$ on the right?
I guess that it only works when $\Omega \in \{0°, 90°, 180°, 270°,...\}$, and ultimately the answer is symmetry. What you call "getting the third quadrant" means that you reflected across the $Y$ axis (sign $+$) and then across the $X$ axis (sign $-$). Basically, to check what a symmetry does you take a point in the "first quadrant" and check where it ends up. 
It's... not the best way to think about it.

Comment: Yes, you got it. Put this in your answer with gruesome details.

Comment: I'd rather not, as I really don't think that this language is the best way to deliver the concept. In fact, it is a very bad way to think about it!

Comment: I think I couldn't explain it simply due to the lack of eloquence. If you feel that you can put the question in better words, feel free to do it. Could you answer this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3830835/826417)?

Answer (score 0):

By definition $\forall \theta$

$$\sin(\pi + \theta) = -\sin(\theta)=\sin(-\theta)$$

as we can check drawing the unitary circle to see that $\sin (\pi + \theta)$ has the same magnitude of $\sin \theta$ but with the reversed sign.

This is a straightforward check for $\theta$ in the first quadrant. For $\theta$ in the second quadrant just consider

$$\alpha=\theta -\frac \pi 2  \implies \theta = \frac \pi 2+\alpha$$

then

$$\sin(\pi + \theta)=\sin\left(\pi +  \frac \pi 2+\alpha\right)=\sin\left( \frac {3\pi} 2+\alpha\right)=-\cos (\alpha)=-\cos\left( \theta -\frac \pi 2\right)=$$

$$=\cos\left( \frac \pi 2-\theta \right)=\sin(\theta)$$

and similarly for all other cases, just using symmetry.

Comment: Do you mean $\theta = 180^\circ$?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout Opsss yes of course! I fix that

Comment: This doesn't help. I know that I can prove it by using sin$(A+B)$. My point was specifically about the quadrants. As sin$(180^° + \theta)$ = $-$sin$(\theta)$, the negative sign comes because $180^° + \theta$ lies in the third quadrant where sin is negative.

Comment: @Cognoscenti Indeed the best way is by definition. Draw the unitary circle and you can easily see that $\sin (\pi + x)$ has the same magnitude of $\sin x$ but with an opposite sign.

Comment: @user Yup, there are many ways to think about it, but I want to know why it works with the quadrant one.

Comment: @Cognoscenti You can prove all this kind of identities by symmetry argument. Just consider the definition on the unitary circle.

Answer (score 0):

For any real $x$ we have $$\sin(\pi+x)=\sin\pi\cos{x}+\cos\pi\sin{x}=-\sin{x}.$$
Id est, $x$ may be ended in any quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would express the idea somewhat differently, I completely agree with
the OP's analysis.

That is, it is **geometrically clear** that $\sin(300^{\circ}) = \pm \sin(120^{\circ}).$

Further, $120^{\circ}$ is in the **second** quadrant while $300^{\circ}$ is in the **fourth** quadrant.

Therefore, $\sin(300^{\circ})$ must be $< 0$, while
$\sin(120^{\circ})$ must be $> 0.$

It could be that reference to the **third** quadrant was an **unnoticed error**, re all angles in the third quadrant (also) have a negative value for their sine.

Comment: Nope, I don't think that the reference to the third quadrant was an error. To decide the sign, $180^° + \theta$ is taken to be in the third quadrant (as if $\theta$ is lesser than $90^°$), even though $180^°+120^°$ does not lie in the third quadrant, but lies in the fourth quadrant. This is consistent with all trigonometric functions. My question was "Why it works?" *(logically, it doesn't make sense to me)*.

Comment: Similarly, $270^° - \theta$ is taken in the third quadrant (**to decide the sign**), no matter what $\theta$ is.

Comment: @Cognoscenti all I can say is that if you are examining the sine or cosine of a specific angle, and you want to base the sign of the trignometric function (positive or negative) on the quadrant that the angle is located in, you have to be totally accurate in identifying the quadrant.  Otherwise, you are asking for trouble.